# How should we deal with users asking more than one question on a single post?

Tags: answers, asking-questions, etiquette, discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multi-Question Questions: How Best to Handle Them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/multi-question-questions-how-best-to-handle-them)

I just want to get a general consensus on how to deal with question posters asking more than one question in one post, especially when they have low or zero accept rate. Is it wrong for me to ask for an upvote/acceptance, if the OP has a track record of not voting/accepting? Or for the OP to post another question when the current question is clearly being answered?

Also, if OPs want to expand on their questions, is it okay to ask them to create new questions instead of comment spamming already answered questions?

Comment: actually, i was wondering if it's ok to "ask" for upvote/answer due to the fact the poster usually don't upvote or accept.  Also if they want to further expand on the posted question is it ok to request them to create another question instead of comment spam an already answered question.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, it's just similar. I edited the OP's reply comment into the post.